# the same formatting control over Web documents that they have over - I can't make proper grammatical sense of it

Tags: grammar

> **Web designers sometimes try to achieve the same formatting control over Web documents that they have over, say, printed documents.** They want what they see on their screens with their browsers to be exactly what any visitor to their sites may also see. (Even if they can’t pronounce WYSIWYG, they want “what you see” to be “what you get.”) Two overarching problems prevent Web designers from achieving this control with HTML:

**Web designers sometimes try to achieve the same formatting control over Web documents that they have over...** And then little can I do to make grammatical sense of the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is implying that:
1. One has a certain level of formatting control when creating printed documents.
2. The level of formatting control available when creating web content is less than that.
3. But web designers sometimes expect the two to be equal even though they aren't.

The 'say' is used as a synonym for "for example"

Put another way: if we call the level of control available for printed documents L1, and the level of control available for web documents L2,
then the author is saying:
  *web designers sometimes expect L2 to be the same as, for example, L1.*